# Como dizer «play footsie» em português?

Tags: tradução, palavra-para-ideia

A expressão inglesa «play footsie» [significa](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/footsie):

> a) to secretly touch someone's feet with your feet under a table to show that you think they are sexually attractive

Como dizer isto em português?
Temos expressões semelhantes?

> - Their date was going well, and with the help of a glass of red wine she decided to *play footsie*.
> - The allure of the forbidden took the best of Jan, and she started *playing footsie* with Michael while David explained the company's new sales and marketing plan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Procurei por aí e tudo o que encontrei foram frases descritivas, como:

> [Fazer carícias com os pés (aquela por debaixo da mesa)](http://www.englishexperts.com.br/forum/como-dizer-flerte-caricias-com-os-pes-em-ingles-t14104.html)
>
> [Tocando pés por debaixo da mesa](http://www.istockphoto.com/br/fotos/tocando+p%C3%A9s+por+debaixo+da+mesa?facets=%7B%22text%22:%5B%22tocando%20p%C3%A9s%20por%20debaixo%20da%20mesa%22%5D,%22pageNumber%22:1,%22perPage%22:100,%22abstractType%22:%5B%22photos%22%5D,%22order%22:%22bestMatch%22,%22f%22:true%7D)
>
> [Mulheres, vcs ja provocaram alguem com o pé por baixo da mesa durante um jantar?](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090203111704AARBKmv)

Portanto se quisermos uma expressão mais compacta, temos de inventar. Em contexto adequado *namoro, namorico ou (ptBR) flerte de pés* seria facilmente compreendido. Para a forma verbal, *namorar, namoricar ou flertar com os pés*. Já houve quem espontaneamente usasse [*namoro de pés*](https://mydreamcomingtrue2011.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/he-hates-me-part-ii/) para coisa parecida

Os teus exemplos poderiam ficar (com tradução muito livre de *date*):

> O jantar corria bem, e com a ajuda de um copo de tinto ela decidiu entrar num namorico de pés.
>
> Jan deixou-se levar pela atração do proibido, e começou a namorar o Michael com o pé, enquanto o David explicava o novo plano de vendas e marketing da empresa.

Answer (score 2):

Existe explicação, descrição, mas não tradução para português, pelo menos não no Brasil. Não é comum a utilização.
Dependendo da região ou companhia pode-se dizer outras coisas como: "estávamos de frescura com os pés" ou "esfregando os pés" etc.
A palavra namorico não é utilizada no Brasil (em geral), embora seja compreendida e correta.